Manage layouts in ALV grid does not work in splitter container
I try to use an ALV grid inside a splitter container.
Currently I am facing a bug when trying to manage variants. The "manage variants" screen is empty.
I think this issue occurs because the ALV parent container is not the cl_gui_container=>default_screen, but the splitter screen instead.
Here is an example to reproduce this issue.
REPORT ztest.

* Referenzen auf GUI-Objekte
* Splitter
DATA: o_splitter_main TYPE REF TO cl_gui_splitter_container.
* Splitter-Container oben
DATA: o_container_o   TYPE REF TO cl_gui_container.
* Splitter-Container unten
DATA: o_container_u   TYPE REF TO cl_gui_container.

* Splitter auf default_screen erzeugen
*https://www.abapforum.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25748
o_splitter_main = NEW #( parent                  = cl_gui_container=>default_screen
                         no_autodef_progid_dynnr = abap_true
                         rows                    = 2
                         columns                 = 1 ).

* Höhe oberer Splitter in %
o_splitter_main->set_row_height( id = 1 height = 50 ).
o_container_o = o_splitter_main->get_container( row = 1 column = 1 ).        " MAIN VIEW
o_container_u = o_splitter_main->get_container( row = 2 column = 1 ).        " DETAIL VIEW


START-OF-SELECTION.
* Daten holen
  SELECT *
    INTO TABLE @DATA(it_spfli)
    FROM spfli.

* ALV-Gitter-Objekt erzeugen
  DATA(o_alv) = NEW cl_gui_alv_grid( i_parent      = o_container_o " in default container einbetten
                                     i_appl_events = abap_true ).                     " Ereignisse als Applikationsevents registrieren

* Feldkatalog automatisch durch SALV-Objekte erstellen lassen
  DATA: o_salv TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table.

  cl_salv_table=>factory( IMPORTING
                            r_salv_table = o_salv
                          CHANGING
                            t_table      = it_spfli ).

  DATA(it_fcat) = cl_salv_controller_metadata=>get_lvc_fieldcatalog( r_columns      = o_salv->get_columns( )
                                                                     r_aggregations = o_salv->get_aggregations( ) ).

  DATA(lv_layout) = VALUE lvc_s_layo(
                                        zebra      = abap_true
                                        cwidth_opt = 'A'
                                        grid_title = 'Testapp'
                                      ).

  DATA ls_variant_det TYPE disvariant.
  ls_variant_det-report   = sy-repid.
  ls_variant_det-username = sy-uname.
  .

* ALV anzeigen
  o_alv->set_table_for_first_display( EXPORTING
                                        i_bypassing_buffer = abap_false  " Puffer ausschalten
                                        i_save             = 'A'         " Anzeigevariante sichern
                                        is_layout          = lv_layout   " Layout
                                        is_variant         = ls_variant_det

                                      CHANGING
                                        it_fieldcatalog    = it_fcat     " Feldkatalog
                                        it_outtab          = it_spfli ). " Ausgabetabelle

* Focus auf ALV setzen
  cl_gui_alv_grid=>set_focus( control = o_alv ).
*
** leere SAP-Toolbar ausblenden
  cl_abap_list_layout=>suppress_toolbar( ).
*
** erzwingen von cl_gui_container=>default_screen
  WRITE: space.


Choose Layout, Change Layout and Save Layout are working.

I'm not going to recommand using this "fix". Put it on a dynpro and don't use the no_autodef_progid_dynnr in the cl_gui_splitter_container. It's really prone to error, when you try abusing the default screen with standard screens.
Here is what you can do. Put everything in the initialization event (or any event before the selection screen) add a dummy parameter to force the selection screen and remove the no_autodef_progid_dynnr from the constructor. The default screen set in there is the standard selection screen 1000. So it will overlay the splitter on the selection screen. The variant management then uses a different screen and you'll see it. Here is the "fixed" example:
report ztest.
* Referenzen auf GUI-Objekte
* Splitter
data: o_splitter_main type ref to cl_gui_splitter_container.
* Splitter-Container oben
data: o_container_o   type ref to cl_gui_container.
* Splitter-Container unten
data: o_container_u   type ref to cl_gui_container.

parameters: dummy.

initialization.
* Splitter auf default_screen erzeugen
*https://www.abapforum.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25748
  o_splitter_main = new #(
                           parent = cl_gui_container=>default_screen
*                           no_autodef_progid_dynnr = abap_true
                           rows                    = 2
                           columns                 = 1 ).

* Höhe oberer Splitter in %
  o_splitter_main->set_row_height( id = 1 height = 50 ).
  o_container_o = o_splitter_main->get_container( row = 1 column = 1 ).
  o_container_u = o_splitter_main->get_container( row = 2 column = 1 ).

* Daten holen
  select *
    into table @data(it_spfli)
    from spfli.

* ALV-Gitter-Objekt erzeugen
  data(o_alv) = new cl_gui_alv_grid( i_parent      = o_container_o " in default container einbetten
                                     i_appl_events = abap_true ).                     " Ereignisse als Applikationsevents registrieren

* Feldkatalog automatisch durch SALV-Objekte erstellen lassen
  data: o_salv type ref to cl_salv_table.

  cl_salv_table=>factory( importing
                            r_salv_table = o_salv
                          changing
                            t_table      = it_spfli ).

  data(it_fcat) = cl_salv_controller_metadata=>get_lvc_fieldcatalog( r_columns      = o_salv->get_columns( )
                                                                     r_aggregations = o_salv->get_aggregations( ) ).

  data(lv_layout) = value lvc_s_layo(
                                        zebra      = abap_true
                                        cwidth_opt = 'A'
                                        grid_title = 'Testapp'
                                      ).

  data ls_variant_det type disvariant.
  ls_variant_det-report   = sy-repid.
  ls_variant_det-username = sy-uname.
  .

* ALV anzeigen
  o_alv->set_table_for_first_display( exporting
                                        i_bypassing_buffer = abap_false  " Puffer ausschalten
                                        i_save             = 'A'         " Anzeigevariante sichern
                                        is_layout          = lv_layout   " Layout
                                        is_variant         = ls_variant_det

                                      changing
                                        it_fieldcatalog    = it_fcat     " Feldkatalog
                                        it_outtab          = it_spfli ). " Ausgabetabelle

* Focus auf ALV setzen
  cl_gui_alv_grid=>set_focus( control = o_alv ).
*
** leere SAP-Toolbar ausblenden
  cl_abap_list_layout=>suppress_toolbar( ).
*
** erzwingen von cl_gui_container=>default_screen
*  write: space.


You have two grid in your code, one of them is cl_salv_table and other one cl_gui_alv_grid.
I tried your code and I saw only very small part of alv with Java Gui. The splitter didn't work. Maybe your report has toolbar object.
I know that you need a screen for both of the,. You can add a empty screen for it and call the screen to show it instead of write command.
REPORT zmky_alv_split.

INCLUDE <ctldef>.

* Referenzen auf GUI-Objekte
* Splitter
DATA: o_splitter_main TYPE REF TO cl_gui_splitter_container.
* Splitter-Container oben
DATA: o_container_o   TYPE REF TO cl_gui_container.
* Splitter-Container unten
DATA: o_container_u   TYPE REF TO cl_gui_container.

* Splitter auf default_screen erzeugen
*https://www.abapforum.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25748
o_splitter_main = NEW #( parent                  = cl_gui_container=>default_screen
                         no_autodef_progid_dynnr = abap_true
                         rows                    = 2
                         columns                 = 1 ).

* Höhe oberer Splitter in %
o_splitter_main->set_row_height( id = 1 height = 50 ).
o_container_o = o_splitter_main->get_container( row = 1 column = 1 ).        " MAIN VIEW
o_container_u = o_splitter_main->get_container( row = 2 column = 1 ).        " DETAIL VIEW


START-OF-SELECTION.
* Daten holen
  SELECT *
    INTO TABLE @DATA(it_spfli)
    FROM spfli.

* ALV-Gitter-Objekt erzeugen
  DATA(o_alv) = NEW cl_gui_alv_grid( i_parent      = o_container_o " in default container einbetten
                                     i_appl_events = abap_true ).                     " Ereignisse als Applikationsevents registrieren
  DATA: it_fcat TYPE lvc_t_fcat.
* Feldkatalog automatisch durch SALV-Objekte erstellen lassen

  DATA(lv_layout) = VALUE lvc_s_layo(
                                        zebra      = abap_true
                                        cwidth_opt = 'A'
                                        grid_title = 'Testapp'
                                      ).

  DATA ls_variant_det TYPE disvariant.
  ls_variant_det-report   = sy-repid.
  ls_variant_det-username = sy-uname.
  .

* ALV anzeigen

* Automatically fill the field catalog
  CALL FUNCTION 'LVC_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE'
    EXPORTING
      i_structure_name = 'SPFLI'
    CHANGING
      ct_fieldcat      = it_fcat
    EXCEPTIONS
      inconsistent_interface = 1
      program_error          = 2
      OTHERS                 = 3.

  o_alv->set_table_for_first_display( EXPORTING
                                        i_bypassing_buffer = abap_false  " Puffer ausschalten
                                        i_save             = 'A'         " Anzeigevariante sichern
                                        is_layout          = lv_layout   " Layout
                                        is_variant         = ls_variant_det

                                      CHANGING
                                        it_fieldcatalog    = it_fcat     " Feldkatalog
                                        it_outtab          = it_spfli ). " Ausgabetabelle


  CALL SCREEN 100.

* Focus auf ALV setzen
  cl_gui_alv_grid=>set_focus( control = o_alv ).
*
** leere SAP-Toolbar ausblenden
  cl_abap_list_layout=>suppress_toolbar( ).

For cl_salv_table, you need to show toolbar functions for layout.
REPORT zmky_cl_salv_table.

INCLUDE <ctldef>.

* Referenzen auf GUI-Objekte
* Splitter
DATA: o_splitter_main TYPE REF TO cl_gui_splitter_container.
* Splitter-Container oben
DATA: o_container_o   TYPE REF TO cl_gui_container.
* Splitter-Container unten
DATA: o_container_u   TYPE REF TO cl_gui_container.

* Splitter auf default_screen erzeugen
*https://www.abapforum.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25748
o_splitter_main = NEW #( parent                  = cl_gui_container=>default_screen
                         no_autodef_progid_dynnr = abap_true
                         rows                    = 2
                         columns                 = 1 ).

* Höhe oberer Splitter in %
o_splitter_main->set_row_height( id = 1 height = 50 ).
o_container_o = o_splitter_main->get_container( row = 1 column = 1 ).        " MAIN VIEW
o_container_u = o_splitter_main->get_container( row = 2 column = 1 ).        " DETAIL VIEW


START-OF-SELECTION.
* Daten holen
  SELECT *
    INTO TABLE @DATA(it_spfli)
    FROM spfli.

* ALV-Gitter-Objekt erzeugen
  DATA: o_salv TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table.

* Feldkatalog automatisch durch SALV-Objekte erstellen lassen
  cl_salv_table=>factory( EXPORTING
                            r_container  = o_container_o
                            container_name = 'TAB_CONTAINER'
                          IMPORTING
                            r_salv_table = o_salv
                          CHANGING
                            t_table      = it_spfli ).

  DATA(it_fcat) = cl_salv_controller_metadata=>get_lvc_fieldcatalog( r_columns      = o_salv->get_columns( )
                                                                     r_aggregations = o_salv->get_aggregations( ) ).

  DATA(lv_layout) = VALUE lvc_s_layo(
                                        zebra      = abap_true
                                        cwidth_opt = 'A'
                                        grid_title = 'Testapp'
                                      ).

  DATA ls_variant_det TYPE disvariant.
  ls_variant_det-report   = sy-repid.
  ls_variant_det-username = sy-uname.
  .

* ALV anzeigen
  o_salv->get_functions( )->set_all( ).
  o_salv->display( ).

  CALL SCREEN 100.
*
** leere SAP-Toolbar ausblenden
  cl_abap_list_layout=>suppress_toolbar( ).


I am sorry, I don't get your code to work.
Maybe there is some kind of missunderstanding too? My problem is, that the 'manage layouts' option of the dropdown does not work, the split container itself is working for me. In my example, I only provided the top screen of the splitter.

Which one didn't work? You need to create a screen 100 for first one. Same here, I also cannot see the ALV as normal and the manage layout button with your code.

The second example shows two empty screens.
The first example behaves exactely like mine. I see the ALV in the top container but after clicking 'manage layouts' - there is an empty screen.

Sorry, I forgot  container parameter for second example. Java and Windows GUI working different. We need a screen both of them. I tried my two example with Window GUI 8 Patch 2 and they worked.
